# How do I get the nREPL port for a running REPL?

Tags: clojure, nrepl

I want to connect to a running REPL on my local machine outside of Visual Studio Code. The terminal output is cleared or truncated depending on the terminal.

Is it possible for me to find the port number that the REPL is running on via a shell command or a Clojure function?

Answer (score 2):

Grep the processes for the name of the project that is running on the JVM. This will give a process ID. Eg. 71141

```
ps aux | grep name-of-the-project
```

Grep the network-related information such as open connections, open socket ports with the process ID from above.

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 71141
```

Find the loopback IP with the associate port. Eg. 63361

```
127.0.0.1.63361
```

Use that port in Visual Studio Code.

---

To find the port from the Clojure REPL: `(slurp ".nrepl-port")`

Answer (score 2):

When the nrepl server starts, it generally writes the port number it is using into the file `.nrepl-port` in the project directory. Most tooling (e.g. emacs CIDER or `lein repl :connect`) use this file.

Comment: Spot on! I actually saw that after I saw the slurp of `.nrepl-port`. Most useful. :D